# How to make invite to a server using createInvite

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So I want to make an invite to default channel of the server command was executed in.

```
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Testt", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTitle("title")
        .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription("description")
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter("© Test", client.user.displayAvatarURL())

        channel.send(embed)
```

So I want invite to be above MessageEmbed

Comment: Discord guilds don't have a default channel anymore. `guild.defaultChannel` is no longer a thing.

Comment: Umm is there a way then to make an invite ?

Comment: Yes, you can use [channel.createInvite()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `defaultChannel` is not a thing anymore I made it like this:

```
let invite = await message.channel.createInvite({
maxAge: 0, // 0 = infinite expiration
maxUses: 0 // 0 = infinite uses
})

message.channel.send(`${invite}`, "test")
```